# Building up a table over several rows, while keeping the amount of TDs limited?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building up a table which consists of two rows.
The first row holds an image, the second row holds the related text.

Only now do I realize that i need to have "max column" of some sort per row.

However, im unable to think of a way to implement this variable max (I tried a bunch, like a while loop and like keeping track of the count done so far).

```
var max = 5 //needs to be flexible
var tr = document.createElement("tr");

for (var i = 0; i < this.structures.length; i++){ //image row
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var img = new Image()
        td.appendChild(img);            
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
table.appendChild(tr);


var tr = document.createElement("tr");

for (var i = 0; i < this.structures.length; i++){ // text row
    var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = "bla"
}
table.appendChild(tr);
```

Can someone advise?

Comment: `var max = Math.min(5, this.structures.length)`, then change your loop conditions to use `max` instead of the length? `i < max`

Comment: Though it seems like you may be using tables for layout. If so, there are usually better ways.

Comment: What do you mean by max column of `sorts` per row ?

Comment: @NadirLaskar: *"of sorts"* isn't referring to any kind of data. It's an expression that means *"of some kind"* or *"by some means"*.

Comment: That does not the solve the problem at hand. If i use max in the loop, i will get 2 rows with 5 elements, instead of lets say 4 rows with 5 elements each and and a fifth row with 2 elements (assuming i have a total of 22 elements).
The problem is im running two loops, one for for an image row, one for an text row which, as far as i can tell, isnt the problem you perceived in your comment. EDIT posted before your answer, squint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying that you actually want more than two rows to hold images greater than the max, then simply create two more every time the value of `i` is evenly divisible by your maximum.

Also, probably a good idea to use separate `tbody` elements since you're creating a grouping that will probably need to be fetched as such.

```js
var structures = [
   {text: "red",   src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/f00"
}, {text: "blue",  src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/00f"
}, {text: "green", src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0"
}, {text: "red",   src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/f00"
}, {text: "blue",  src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/00f"
}, {text: "green", src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0"
}, {text: "red",   src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/f00"
}, {text: "blue",  src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/00f"
}, {text: "green", src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0"
}, {text: "red",   src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/f00"
}, {text: "blue",  src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/00f"
}, {text: "green", src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0"
}];

var max = 5;
var table = document.querySelector("#t");
var tbody, tr1, tr2;

for (var i = 0; i < structures.length; i++) {
  if (i % max === 0) {
    tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
    tr1 = tbody.insertRow(-1);
    tr2 = tbody.insertRow(-1);
  }
  tr1.insertCell(-1).appendChild(new Image()).src = structures[i].src;
  tr2.insertCell(-1).textContent = i + ": " + structures[i].text;
}
```

```html
<table id=t></table>
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, i will look into it. much appreciated.

Comment: @user431806: I'm working on an edit to continue displaying on subsequent rows. Should have it in a couple minutes.

Comment: Ah, thats awesome. Thanks for the effort. I will make sure to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that adds rows to the table as needed by the content

I have used an array `row_set`

`var row_set = [];` it stores all the rows of the table.

And Inside the for loop I called a function `getRows()` that give me an array of two rows to add data.

`getRows` is shown below

It takes two parameters `current` and `row`.

`current` is the current index and `max` is the maximum.

```
function getRows(current,max){
  if(current%max === 0){
    row_set.push(table.insertRow(-1));
    row_set.push(table.insertRow(-1));
  }

  return row_set;
}
```

It returns an array of two news rows if `current` is divided by `max` or else returns the last array of rows.

Now, Pop the two rows and add your data.

```
tr2= rows.pop();
tr1= rows.pop();
```

After adding the data to the tables push the last used rows in the `row_set` array.

```
rows.push(tr1);
rows.push(tr2);
```

```js
var structures = [
   {text: "red",   src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/f00"
}, {text: "blue",  src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/00f"
}, {text: "green", src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0"
}, {text: "red",   src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/f00"
}, {text: "blue",  src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/00f"
}, {text: "green", src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0"
}, {text: "red",   src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/f00"
}, {text: "blue",  src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/00f"
}, {text: "green", src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0"
}, {text: "red",   src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/f00"
}, {text: "blue",  src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/00f"
}, {text: "green", src: "http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0"
}];

var max = 5;
var table = document.querySelector("#t");
var tr1, tr2;
  
var row_set = [];

for (var i = 0; i < structures.length; i++){
  
  var rows = getRows(i,max);
  
  tr2= rows.pop();
  tr1= rows.pop();
  
  tr1.appendChild(document.createElement("td"))
     .appendChild(new Image())
     .src = structures[i].src;
  
  tr2.appendChild(document.createElement("td"))
     .textContent = structures[i].text;
  
  rows.push(tr1);
  rows.push(tr2);
}



function getRows(current,max){
  if(current%max === 0){
    row_set.push(table.insertRow(-1));
    row_set.push(table.insertRow(-1));
  }
  
  return row_set;
}
```

```html
<table id=t></table>
```

Comment: wow, this one looks really interesting, too. I will definitly try to remember the technique for the future. thanks for the effort.